# MarkLogic triple objects language

Tags: xquery, marklogic, triplestore, triples

I'm in a tricky situation and I can't seem to find any information in the MarkLogic documentation about it. 
The problem I'm having is that I am using triples from different sources and they are using different ways of describing string objects (some are multilingual):

```
<http://subject1> <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel> "Object"^^xs:string .
<http://subject2> <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel> "Object"@en .
```

So when I do a 
`cts:triples((), sem:iri("http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel"), "Object")`
then I only get the first triple.

The question is, how do I make it ignore the language and return the two triples (if possible, without using sparql)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interestingly enough using "Object" like above didn't return results at all for me (using MarkLogic 7.0-4.1 on MacOS). Instead I had to use:

```
cts:triples((),(),(
  sem:unknown("Object", sem:iri("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemastring")),
  rdf:langString("Object", "en")
))
```

Here some longer piece of code that you can run in QConsole (run it against an empty database!) to better understand what is going on:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics"
       at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";
sem:rdf-insert(sem:rdf-parse('
@prefix xs:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema> .
<http://subject1> <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel> "Object"^^xs:string .
<http://subject2> <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel> "Object"@en .
', "turtle"))
;

'all triples:',
cts:triples((),(),()),

'all objects:',
for $triple in cts:triples((),(),())
return xdmp:describe(sem:triple-object($triple)),

'all object languages:',
for $triple in cts:triples((),(),())
return concat('"', sem:lang(sem:triple-object($triple)), '"'),

'results with "Object":',
cts:triples((),(),sem:iri("Object")),

'results with sem:unknown("Object", sem:iri("xs:string")):',
cts:triples((),(),sem:unknown("Object", sem:iri("xs:string"))),

'results with sem:unknown("Object", sem:iri("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemastring")):',
cts:triples((),(),sem:unknown("Object", sem:iri("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemastring"))),

'results with rdf:langString("Object", "en")',
cts:triples((),(),rdf:langString("Object", "en")),

'combined results:',
cts:triples((),(),(
  sem:unknown("Object", sem:iri("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemastring")),
  rdf:langString("Object", "en")
))
```

HTH!